# How to add pagination to the query?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

Before I was simply doing a query that selects some field and some conditions. This line of code is giving me the correct result.

```
public function index()
{
    // Get links
    $links = Link::select('id', 'url', 'short_url', 'counter', 'expired_on')
        ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
        ->where('delete_flg', 0)
        ->get();

    // Return data
    return view('dashboard')->with(
        array(
            'links' => json_decode($links),
            'current_datetime' => Carbon::now()
        )
    );
}
```

Now I want to implement pagination to the above line.

```
$links = Link::select('id', 'url', 'short_url', 'counter', 'expired_on')
    ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
    ->where('delete_flg', 0)
    ->get()->paginate(2);
```

When I try using paginate(2) at the end I get error:

```
Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::paginate does not exist.
```

So from some other tutorial I tried without ->get() and then paginate
Then I get such error.

```
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable
```

I am confused on how to implement paginate.

Can anybody please help me?

Comment: You should use `paginate()` instead of `get()` so if you remove `->get()` from that query, it should work. https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/pagination

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply do following:

```
$links = Link::select('id', 'url', 'short_url', 'counter', 'expired_on')
            ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
            ->where('delete_flg', 0)
            ->paginate(2);
```

paginate already acts like a `->get()`

And this is how you return the data / collection to your view:

```
// return data
return view('dashboard', compact('links'));
```

Alternative to compact:

```
return view('dashboard')->with([
    'links' => $links
]);
```

Then in your view you can do whatever you wish to do with the data:

```
@foreach($links as $link)
    <p>{{ link }}</p>
@endforeach
```

Comment: yes I removed get() and then used  return view('dashboard')->with(
            array(
                'links' => json_decode($links),
                'current_datetime' => Carbon::now()
            )
        );

but i get error

Comment: @user1687891 can you do it like I did it above `return view('dashboard')->compact('links');
` and tell me what error you get

Comment: @user1687891 - _"but i get error"_ ... that says what?

Comment: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: ok can you you output $links in your controller method like this: dd($links) and tell us the returned result

Comment: #items: Collection {#256 ▼
    #items: array:2 [▼
      0 => Link {#258 ▼
        #table: "links"
        +primaryKey: "id"
        #fillable: array:3 [▶]
        #connection: "mysql"
        #keyType: "int"
        +incrementing: true
        #with: []
        #withCount: []
        #perPage: 15
        +exists: true
        +wasRecentlyCreated: false
        #attributes: array:5 [▼
          "id" => 18
          "url" => "https://www.fff.com/"
          "short_url" => "FeURjm"
          "counter" => 0
          "expired_on" => "2020-10-10 17:04:00"
        ]

Comment: @user1687891 just as Magnus says remove the `json_decode()` just use laravel 's `compact` method like I wrote it in my answer

Comment: @utdev if i use compact i get Method Illuminate\View\View::compact does not exist.

Comment: @user1687891 hhmm strange I update my answer with an alternative to compact try that please

Comment: @utdev laravel behave strangly to me today .. thank for the help

Comment: @user1687891 I had a typo mistake in my answer you could try to use compact against like this `return view('dashboard', compact('links'));
`

Answer (score 0):

This is a [documented change in PHP 7.2](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/counting_non_countables). You need to either update Laravel to 5.6+ or downgrade PHP to version 7.1.

Furthermore you have to use `paginate()` without `->get()`, you should also take a look at the [pagination documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/pagination).